How do I delete a certain task after a complete button from that same task is deleted?
I'm making a task management system, but I can't seem to figure out how to check if a specific button was pressed from a task, and delete that same task with the button that was pressed.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log("1");
  document.querySelector("#add-new-btn") ? .addEventListener("click", function() {
    const iValue = document.querySelector("input") ? .value;
    if (iValue == "") {
      console.warn("All fields must be filled out");
      alert("Please enter a task description!");
    } else {
      const taskDiv = document.createElement("div");
      taskDiv.className = "task"
      const taskDesc = document.createElement("p");
      taskDesc.innerHTML = iValue;
      taskDiv.appendChild(taskDesc);
      const taskCompBtn = document.createElement("button")
      taskCompBtn.textContent = "Complete"
      taskCompBtn.id = "compBtn"
      taskDiv.appendChild(taskCompBtn);

      const taskContainer = document.querySelector(".tasks-container");
      taskContainer ? .appendChild(taskDiv);
    }
  });
  document.querySelector("#compBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('Completed task')
  })
});
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>To-do list app</h1>
    <p>An amazing to-do list application</p>
  </div>
  <div class="add-new-container">
    <h3>Add new Task</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Description..">
    <button id="add-new-btn">Add Task</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tasks-container">
    <!-- <div class="task">
            <p>[EX] Wash the dog</p>
            <button>Complete</button>
        </div> -->
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>



I've tried using an id in the past, and assigning an id to each task, but I wasn't quite sure how to check the id's properly (if that makes sense).

Have you checked your dev console for errors?

When you add the id taskCompBtn.id = "compBtn", you won't have unique id when adding task. You better use class or add a counter that you can use it in id

"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'",   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno": 31,   "colno": 44

You can use this code. First when you select a DOM element make sure it is already appended. I also remeved the id on btn otherwise it won't be unique and replaced with class. Then I loop through the btns to check for click and then select the parent element that contains both the task and btn to be removed.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log("1");
    document.querySelector("#add-new-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        const iValue = document.querySelector("input").value;
        if (iValue == "") {
            console.warn("All fields must be filled out");
            alert("Please enter a task description!");
        } else {
            const taskDiv = document.createElement("div");
            taskDiv.className = "task"
            const taskDesc = document.createElement("p");
            taskDesc.innerHTML = iValue;
            taskDiv.appendChild(taskDesc);
            const taskCompBtn = document.createElement("button")
            taskCompBtn.textContent = "Complete"
            taskCompBtn.classList.add('compBtn')
            taskDiv.appendChild(taskCompBtn);
            const taskContainer = document.querySelector(".tasks-container");
            taskContainer.appendChild(taskDiv);
            const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".compBtn")
            btns.forEach(btn=>btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                let tasktoDelete = btn.parentElement
                tasktoDelete.remove()
            }))

        }
    });
});
<div class="header">
        <h1>To-do list app</h1>
        <p>An amazing to-do list application</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-new-container">
        <h3>Add new Task</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description..">
        <button id="add-new-btn">Add Task</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tasks-container">
        <!-- <div class="task">
            <p>[EX] Wash the dog</p>
            <button>Complete</button>
        </div> -->
    </div>



.

This const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".compBtn") selects all buttons with the same class, adding click listener several times on existing buttons, it's not a good approach. You should attach a new event listener only on new buttons.

I am actualy selecting all btns but adding eventListener only once and on each single btn. I also like your constructor approach.

Yes, you are adding eventListener once, but every time you create a new button you add again a eventListener to all existing buttons. Add console.count('clicked'); after tasktoDelete.remove() and see how many times the action is executed, it should be once per click, it's not.

Same thing happens with your constructor method. You also do have as much click counts( if not more, even without taking into account the addtask btn click).

I do not agree, I made a Pen to support my point, take a look: https://codepen.io/DanieleAlessandra/full/oNRjGwB

@DanieleAlessandra, first I like the way you code. Now I am no doubt convinced. I have faced event propagation problem but could not solve it. With your method by adding listener to newly created btns (and keeping it on previous ones) we don't have this problem anymore. Great approach and did not know about it. Was always seeing the one I wrote! (so +1 no doubt!)

Your problem is that when you try to add a click listener to the button, the button itself does not exist.
Common solutions to this problem are:

Attach the event listener to each button just after creation.
Attach the event listener to a higher-level element, like the whole document.

Here is an example:
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.closest(".compBtn")) {
    (function() {
      this.parentNode.remove();
    }).call(event.target, event);
  }
});

This snippet:

Adds a click event listener to the document.
Checks if the element you clicked has the class compBtn (I am using a class because you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID in your DOM).
Defines a function.
Inside that function, removes the parent element of the clicked one.
Calls the function, passing the clicked element as the context.

So, every time you click something, the document click listener is executed. If you clicked on a button with the class compBtn, the parent element of the button itself is removed from the DOM. You don’t need the button to exist on page load.
Please, remember that you need to change id to class for this to work:
// REMOVE --> taskCompBtn.id = "compBtn"
taskCompBtn.className = "compBtn"; // <-- ADD


add your event listener when you are creating the task (in the else portion of your code)


 document.querySelector("#add-new-btn")?.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const iValue = document.querySelector("input")?.value;
        if (iValue == "") {
            console.warn("All fields must be filled out");
            alert("Please enter a task description!");
        } else {
        
            const taskDiv = document.createElement("div");
            taskDiv.className = "task";
            
            const taskDesc = document.createElement("p");
            taskDesc.innerHTML = iValue;
            taskDiv.appendChild(taskDesc);
            
            const taskCompBtn = document.createElement("button")
            taskCompBtn.textContent = "Complete"
            taskCompBtn.id = "compBtn"
            taskDiv.appendChild(taskCompBtn);

            const taskContainer = document.querySelector(".tasks-container");
            taskContainer?.appendChild(taskDiv);
            
            taskCompBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log('Completed task');
            taskContainer?.removeChild(taskDiv);
              console.log('Deleted task');
            });
        }
    });
   
 <div class="header">
        <h1>To-do list app</h1>
        <p>An amazing to-do list application</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-new-container">
        <h3>Add new Task</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description..">
        <button id="add-new-btn">Add Task</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tasks-container">
        <!-- <div class="task">
            <p>[EX] Wash the dog</p>
            <button>Complete</button>
        </div> -->
    </div>




This answer is better than the accepted one.
